# Applying for a physics Master's in a European university with intention to do Ph.D. in the same group?

Tags: phd, masters, application

I intend to apply to European Master's programs in theoretical physics, and I've got my bachelor's degree in my country Thailand.

I also would like to continue my Ph.D. on my master's thesis subject, with the same professor, of course after finishing the Master's.

How could I make sure before applying for masters which of the professors would certainly accept their own Master's students to be their Ph.D. students, as well? Under which conditions?

Answer (score 1):

> How could I make sure before applying for masters which of the professors would certainly accept their own masters students to be their phd student,as well?

There's no way you can guarantee this. A master's thesis is also a kind of probation period in which a professor assesses the student's qualities or how the student fits within their research group. If, at the end of the master's thesis, a professor thinks that a student is not a good fit for the group, for whatever reason, they will very likely not accept the student for a PhD. In general, you cannot know in advance whether you will meet a professor's expectations, even if you are a good student.

Likewise, during your master's thesis you will also assess the professor, and maybe at the end of your thesis you will decide that you no longer want to do your PhD under the guidance of that professor, as many stories on this site recount.

In addition to the above, a professor might decide to abandon a certain line of research, depending on funding, ideas etc. and your master's thesis is not guaranteed to have a future. Finally, in some countries, PhD admissions are managed by a central committee and a professor might not have much saying in the admission. Even if you prove valuable during your master's thesis, a committee might select candidates who better fulfil other criteria.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Could  you name the countries?

Comment: @Yalda I don't have a list of countries where the admission is managed centrally, but certainly this is done at least in my country, Italy.